# Add contacts using PHP Api with AgileCRM

Tags: php, agile-crm

I have implemented on Add contact to AgileCRM with PHP API then

In `agile_curl_wrap` function, I have provided three requirements with Domain, User and Api_key after clicking submit, I got `401 UNAUTHORIZE` response back.

I'm sure that I have set all requirement needed with this API. I really got stuck in this step.

Thank in advance for any helps.

Comment: Can you put a var_dump on $url variable before call curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url) to I see the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can check that gist I've created to show you how it works. Just replace the strings on both files and go on!

In [AgileCRM PHP Wrap](https://gist.github.com/TiagoGouvea/fcee96d107e8a8e7b816) replace:

```
define("AGILE_DOMAIN", "yourDomain");
define("AGILE_USER_EMAIL", "yourEmail");
define("AGILE_REST_API_KEY", "yourApiKey");
```

In [AgileCRM PHP Wrap usage](https://gist.github.com/TiagoGouvea/65f12b3fa9bd5a6cde3f) replace:

```
$email = "some@email.com";
```

And it must work!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue "401 UNAUTHORIZE". Fixed it by changing AGILE_USER_EMAIL

Please provide your valid admin email of your Agile email id at **AGILE_USER_EMAIL** area and make sure you have added valid **AGILE_DOMAIN** and **AGILE_REST_API_KEY**